# Proving Direct Sum

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Claim. Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$, and suppose that $W_1$, $W_2$, and $W_3$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $W_1 + W_3 = W_2 + W_3$. Then $W_1 = W_2$.

I know that this claim is false, but other than using a span, I do not know how to go about proving this equation...

Comment: pick any three distinct one dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: I've tried this example....such that W1= (x,0), W2= (0,y), but there is no W3 that will make W1+W3=W2+W3

Comment: How about $W_3 = (1,1)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment: $W_1=sp\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $W_2=sp\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $W_3=sp\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ would do.

Then see that $W_1+W_3=W_2+W_3=\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: I haven't learned span yet. Is it possible without span?

Comment: @fred What concepts are you comfortable with? Can you give an example of a space and a subspace?

Comment: Yes I know the definitions of spaces and subspaces, but spans are learned next chapter.

Comment: @fred Can you provide an example of a vector space and a subspace?

Comment: V= {(x,y,0) exists in F^3 such that x,y exist in F} and W=(1,1,0)

Comment: Note that $W=(1,1,0)$ is not a subspace, it is just an element and you are veering dangerously into the concept of "span". Perhaps you do have an inherent notion of span without actually knowing it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13118/discussion-between-blackadder-and-fred)